# Using pointers to local variables in a multi threaded program in C++

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

Lets say there are 4 consumer threads that run in a loop continuously

```
function consumerLoop(threadIndex)
{
    int myArray[100];

    main loop {
    ..process data..
    myArray[myIndex] += newValue
    }
}
```

I have another monitor thread which does other background tasks.
I need to access the `myArray` for each of these threads from the monitor thread.

Assume that the loops will run for ever(so the local variables would exist) and the only operation required from the monitor thread is to read the array contents of all the threads.

One alternative is to change `myArray` to a global array of arrays. But i am guessing that would slow down the consumer loops.

What are the ill effects of declaring a global pointer array
`int *p[4];` and assigning each element to the address of the local variable by adding a line in consumerLoop like so `p[threadIndex] = myArray` and accessing p from monitor thread?

Note: I am running It in a linux system and the language is C++. I am not concerned about synchronization/validity of the array contents when i am accessing it from the monitor thread.Lets stay away from a discussion of locking

Comment: why don't you allocate the MyArray for each consumer thread in the main thread, and pass the address to the consumer thread, along with a mutex to avoid syncronization problems?

Comment: You didn't tell us on what OS and what thread system you are. Not all thread models allow one thread access to the local variables of another. E.g for C11 threads this feature is implementation defined, it may be there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really interested in the performance difference, you have to measure. I would guess, that there are nearly no differenced.

Both approaches are correct, as long as the monitor thread doesn't access stack local variables that are invalid because the function returned.

Answer (score -2):

You can not access myArray from different thread because it is local variable. 
You can do 1) Use glibal variable or 2) Malloca and pass the address to all threads.
Please protect the critical section when all threads rush to use the common memory.

Comment: im not accessing directly. i am storing the address in a global pointer and and accessing that.

Comment: you are using global variable so you have to use mutex or semaphore to protect that variable from simultaneous access of threads.

Comment: i have added an extra comment in the question. I am not interested in the synchronization perspective. i am okay with reading an incorrect value while the value is being edited at the same time